# How to increase dcachesize on a VPS

Tags: memory, centos, vps

I have a VPS running CentOS 5.7 (Final), 32-bit.

When I run `cat /proc/user_beancounters` I see 18923 failcnt on `privvmpages` and 3396932 failcnt on `dcachesize`.  They have a limit of 131072 and 4608000 respectively.  I believe I need to increase my dcachesize on my VPS, but I'm not sure where to set that.

The errors I've been getting are mostly "Cannot allocate memory," especially with PHP.  In `/etc/php.ini` I have `memory_limit = 32M`.  I had tried other values like 64M and 128M, but they didn't work out.  I read in some places that it can't be set too large, or too many processes will be started at once which will exceed my VPS's overall RAM capacity, which is 512MB.

My VPS isn't too heavily burdened.  The load averages are often less than 1.00 for all three values.  I am running phpBB and some WordPress blogs; I have lots of polls on my website that use a mySQL backend.  These issues have only occurred since yesterday after I did a huge `yum update` that downloaded about 238 packages.  In hindsight I probably should not have done them all at once or only installed the ones I really need.  It caused some other issues, but I'll save those for another question.

What I'm looking for here is how to increase `dcachesize`.  Thanks!

(Google searches have not helped me pinpoint the location of the config file where I can adjust this... or some other procedure.)

Comment: This sounds like a ServerFault question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very common problem for OpenVZ problem.
You won't have permission to set the user_beancounters values.
It was set by your provider, they use it to limit your resource usage.
Try contract them and ask for solution.

Comment: Thanks; I guess I don't have any control over it.  I don't recall my usage before the huge yum update, so I have no clue where to start looking to reduce the usage.

It's okay, though.  Since this question, I've just bought a new VPS (with better hardware) and copied everything over.  Guess starting over can always be nice sometimes.